# Use LESS to factor out a CSS rule (e.g. font-size: 20px; )

Tags: less

How would you define a CSS style (e.g. `font-size: 20px`), and reuse it in multiple places with LESS?

According to the LESS docs, I can use variables for keys (e.g. font-size), identifiers (e.g. `.myClass`), and values (e.g. `20px`). However, I'm not seeing an ability to do general rules like this.

**Example in SCSS:**

Define a mixin

```
@mixin large-text {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Use it elsewhere

```
.MyAwesomeTitle {
  color: red;
  @include large-text;
}
```

Result:

```
.MyAwesomeTitle {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Less also has mixins, as shown in [the docs](http://lesscss.org/features/).

Comment: @jonrsharpe - LESS docs only specify how to use mixins with selectors. In my example, I'm not trying to include another class's CSS block.

Comment: It would be helpful to mention that when asking. Also: [*"You can also use parametric mixins which don't take parameters. This is useful if you want to hide the ruleset from the CSS output, but want to include its properties in other rulesets:"*](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Define the mixin. While the leading `.` makes it look like a class selector, it's just how naming mixins works in LESS.

   ```
   .large-text() {
     font-size: 20px;
   }
   ```
2. You include a mixin by just writing the name of the mixin. In this case it's `.large-text`.

   ```
   .MyAwesomeTitle {
     color: red;
     .large-text
   }
   ```

The docs give an example under [*"parametric mixins"*](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature)

Input:

```
.wrap() {
  text-wrap: wrap;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

pre { .wrap }
```

Output:

```
pre {
  text-wrap: wrap;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```